# Cycle through finite set of colours for indefinite set of data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to show stock data. I have seven colours I want to iterate through for the objects. When I add an 8th object, I want it's colour on the chart to be the first colour in the colour array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = document.getElementById('positions_chart');
  var ctx = context.getContext("2d");

  var quantities = [];
    $("#positions_chart").data('positions').forEach(function(element){
      quantities.push(element['quantity']);
  });

  var colors =[ "#FFCE56",
            "#FFA75D",
            "#46BFBF",
            "#5975CB",
            "#FF5D5D",
            "#FFCC5D",
            "#52DF52",
            'black'
];

  var tickers = [];
  $("#positions_chart").data('positions').forEach(function(element){
    tickers.push(element['ticker']);
  });



  var pieData = {
    labels: tickers,
    datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: [
            "#FFCE56",
            "#FFA75D",
            "#46BFBF",
            "#5975CB",
            "#FF5D5D",
            "#FFCC5D",
            "#52DF52",
            'black'

          ],
      borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: quantities
  }  
]
}

var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: pieData,
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }
});
```

The number of tickers indicate how many objects will need a colour on the chart. Cycling through the tickers to assign new colours is something ChartJS does in the background. The problem I'm facing is when **tickers amount** > **colours amount** I want the colours array to reset from the top. So I don't have blank colours for new objects in the chart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch out the colors array with a doubly-linked list.

Or just use an anonymous function on the object creation,

```
datasets: [{backgroundColor: (() => {
  let bgcolors = [];
  for (let i=0; i < tickers.length; ++i) bgcolors.push(colors[i % colors.length]);
  return bgcolors;
  })()
}]
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Here's a somewhat more direct version: ```backgroundColor: tickers.map((t, i) => colors[i % colors.length])```